# Why Toggle feature is not working on homepage in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I trying to create the site mobile friendly. I almost completed but toggling the menu for mobile view is not working on homepage. When I am on homepage Toggle menu is not working. If I open some other page or menu then toggle features is working. I couldn't figure out what I missed. Here I am sharing the index.html page code, CSS and JavaScript code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #6EAD50;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.topnav a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 17px 17px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #373538;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #e3cc67fc;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e3cc67fc;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="{$config{base_url}}">Home</a>

  <a href="{$config{base_url}}/help/index.html">Help</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Browse 
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="{$config{base_url}}/view/year/">Years</a>
      <a href="{$config{base_url}}/view/subjects/">Subjects</a>
      <a href="{$config{base_url}}/view/divisions/">Divisions</a>
      <a href="{$config{base_url}}/view/creators/">Authors</a>
      <a href="{$config{base_url}}/view/indexdbase/">Index Databases</a>
      <a href="{$config{base_url}}/view/type/">Document Type</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="{$config{base_url}}/information.html">About</a>
  <a href="{$config{base_url}}/policies.html">Policies</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a runnable snippet, but you seem to be using a framework or library (`{$config{base-url}}`, for example), could you edit the code to be accurately representative and workable, either by including the library or framework, or by adding substitute attribute-properties and values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this is your **Javascript** file

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

Instead of this you can use it

```
const navToggle = () => document.querySelector(".topnav").classList.toggle("responsive");
```

Toggle function will do the sama thing that its name represents.
if your element has *any class of your choice assume* **responsive** then it will remove it else add it.